# Cannot make JQuery dropdownchecklist to work

Tags: jquery, html, dropdownchecklist

I am trying JQuery dropdownchecklist for the first time.
I downloaded v.1.5 unpacked zip file and copied files to the appropriate places in my project.
Whenever I am starting it, I am getting on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdownchecklist is not a function (23:35:56:023 | error, javascript)
>           at (anonymous function) (public_html/index.html:18:29)
>           at m.Callbacks.j (public_html/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:27295)
>           at m.Callbacks.k.fireWith (public_html/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:28108)
>           at m.extend.ready (public_html/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:29942)
>           at J (public_html/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:30308)
>       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (23:35:56:036 | error, network)

Here is snippet of my HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery/smoothness-1.11.2/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/protopop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".alist").dropdownchecklist({ firstItemChecksAll: true });
    })
</script>
```

Somehow it does not recognize the function. I double checked the spelling and path to the files. Everything looks correct. I would appreciate the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
Apparently, down the HTML body I had another function call that was in fact overwriting the script. After I removed it (I'll rewrite it later) everything started working properly.